# How to make exiftool use data not in the file's tags

Tags: gpx, exiftool

https://www.exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#Advanced-formatting-feature tells how exiftool can be used to create more complicated files.  I use that feature to create a GPX file from the GPS data from all images in a directory.

I would like a way to specify on the exiftool command line two strings for exiftool to put into the `<name>` and `<desc>` elements that can appear once at the beginning of the GPX file.

A less desirable approach would be for the format file to create a dummy string instead of the standard starting `<gpx>` tag and replace that afterward.  But putting it on the command line would be better.  Or in a shell variable that exiftool can access.

Comment: The answer involves the option -UserParam — I invite someone more experienced than me to write an answer explaining how.  I got my script to work using that feature.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74504661/how-to-make-exiftool-use-data-not-in-the-files-tags) is the related post and answer on Github.